# Checkbox values not saved correctly into a wordpress meta array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, checkbox, meta

I am trying to save the checkbox fields in an array into a user meta key. With the below code I am getting the error below:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in xyz path on line 54 value="">
>
> Notice:Undefined offset: 2 in xyz path on line 54 value="">
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in xyz path on line 54 value="">
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in xyz path on line 54 value="">
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in xyz path on line 54 value="">
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in xyz path on line 54 value="">

```
$dps_is_store_closed = get_user_meta($user_id, '_dps_is_store_closed', true);
$daysweek2 = array(
'0' => 'Monday',
'1' => 'Tuesday',
'2' => 'Wednesday',
'3' => 'Thursday',
'4' => 'Friday',
'5' => 'Saturday',
'6' => 'Sunday',
);
<table border="0">
  <tr>
     <th>Closed for the Day</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   foreach($daysweek2 as $key => $value){
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]" name="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]" <?php checked( $dps_is_store_closed[$key], 'on' ); ?> value="">    
    </td>
   }
</tr>
```

Comment: change `<input type="checkbox" id="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]" name="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]" <?php checked( $dps_is_store_closed[$key], 'on' ); ?> value="">`  to this  `<input type="checkbox" id="dps_is_store_closed[<?php echo $key;?>]" name="dps_is_store_closed[<?php echo $key;?>]" <?php checked( $value, 'on' ); ?> value=""> `

Comment: I think it should be for example `id="<?php echo $dps_is_store_closed[$key]; ?>"` - change the `name` like that too

Comment: The above solution resolves the current error. The next problem i am facing is on saving the post value. The checkbox that are not checked is showing  Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /path on line 63
value="on">

Comment: For example: Array
(
    [0] => on
    [1] => on
    [2] => on
    [4] => on
    [5] => on
    [6] => on
)  [3] is not inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your input tag should be:

```
id="dps_is_store_closed[<?php echo $key;?>]"
```

instead:

```
id="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]"
```

And:

```
name="dps_is_store_closed[<?php echo $key;?>]"
```

instead:

```
name="dps_is_store_closed[<?php $key?>]"
```

Comment: The next problem i am facing is on saving the post value. The checkbox that are not checked is showing Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /path on line 63 value="on"> For example: Array ( [0] => on [1] => on [2] => on [4] => on [5] => on [6] => on ) [3] -> '' is not inserted

Comment: Have you tried `checked($dps_is_store_closed[$key], 1, false)`?

Comment: After adding another value in hidden input resolved this issue For example: <input type="hidden" name="dps_is_vendor_closed[<?php echo $key?>]" value="off">